# How to debug programms written in fasm under linux using gdb?

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, debugging, fasm

I wrote simple "hello, world" in fasm, and its works, but how i can generate debug info for gdb and edb (Evan's Debugger)? Fasm compiler could only produce debugging symbols in its specific format - "fas", which of course gbd couldn't understood.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible at the moment.
GDB does not understand the .fas format so you first need to convert the .fas file to [DWARF](http://dwarfstd.org/), but no such converter exists. Tomasz has [asked for help](http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=9792) with format converters so if you feel you're up for the task you should give it a shot.